# Pandas dataframe to nested dictionary with a name space as None

Tags: python, pandas, pyomo

I have a pd dataframe like this and need to convert into dictionary with a None namespace and dataframe as nested?

[pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alPYz.png)

```
data = {None: {
    'Periods': {None: 8759},
    'Years': {None: 20},
    'Scenarios': {None: 1},
    'Scenario_Weight': {1: 1},
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) + [`DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

```
data = {None : df.pivot(index='Index', columns='Key', values='Value').to_dict()}
```

Or:

```
data = {None : df.pivot(*df).to_dict()}
```

If necessary replace blanks:

```
data = {None : df.replace(r'^\s*$', None, regex=True).pivot(*df).to_dict()}
```